# Is there a Firefox/Firebug equivalent of Chrome's jQuery Debugger extension?

Tags: jquery, debugging, firefox

There's a really great extension for Chrome called [jQuery Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi) that lets me inspect any element and see all the jQuery events associated with it:

[image]

I've just run into an issue that's only happening in Firefox, and am wondering if there's some way to see this same data there. All I can seem to find is this:

[image]

which tells me that there IS a click function on this element, but doesn't actually tell me what the function is.

*ETA*

For Sprintster, here's what I see when I look at the element in Firebug without Firequery enabled:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Visual Event to see if that helps you find it?

Comment: @KevinB, yes, Visual Event is helpful in a lot of cases, but for this particular page it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @PalashMondal - I'm already using Firebug. It doesn't give me what I need.

Comment: If you click on the function(), does it not take you to the code?

Comment: @Sprintstar - nope. In fact, since I installed Firequery, clicking on the function doesn't do anything at all. I'm going to disable it and then try again; I'll add a screenshot to the OP of what I get. It doesn't show me the actual click code.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the extension\

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [firequery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/)

Comment: It looked like it might be what I need, but I still can't seem to find the code that's attached to a specific element's click event the way I can with jQuery Debugger. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place?